# Twitter Plugin for Grails - unsuccessful login

Tags: grails, twitter, twitter-oauth, grails-plugin

I'm trying to use the Grails Twitter Plugin - http://www.grails.org/plugin/twitter
I have tried to use it after following the instructions on that page and I always get a
**Sorry, authentication failed** message when trying to login.

Anyone else had this issue and solved it? Also, I'm curious why the instructions say nothing about adding my key/secret to a config file?

Answer (score 2):

The twitter plugin hasn't been updated to use OAuth yet. Use http://grails.org/plugin/twitter4j/ until then.

Comment: I was confused by this because it seems to be one twitter account. Not one for each one of my users that opts to connect themselves to twitter. Am I missing something about the Twitter4j library? What about OAuth 1.0a? Is that part of this plugin? GSPs that bounce you to their site and handle a callback?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use Oauth plugin: http://www.grails.org/plugin/oauth

It's base on scribe framework. It's very easy to work with various social networks. You can anthorize, handle resource from rest api.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using spring security for grails, then you can use [spring-security-twitter plugin](https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-twitter)

Actually I'm a author of this plugin, so feel free to contact me, if there'll be any troubles with it. It ready to use, but still isn't published to central repository, I hope i'll make it next week :)

Comment: What should you do if you are not using Spring Security? I've got Facebook logins as primary login. And if you add Twitter creds you will get added functionality. Well, that is the plan at least.

Comment: I don't know :( as for me I recommend you to use it, it's really helpful

Comment: I will on my next few projects but I'd hate to re-architect what I have now for a secondary login creds which I'm not even sure how that works with Spring Security. What did developers do before your plugin? Is there no sites online that use OAuth 1.0 against Twitter and are written in Grails?

Comment: Probably they'd written their own code on top Spring Security :)

Comment: I'm looking over your code... Trying to see if I can follow everything that you are doing. Where is the hashing & exchange happening. Forgive me if I'm using incorrect terminology I'm still trying to get my head around OAuth 1.0. +1 Is it just me or is OAuth 2.0 much easier?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to ask Igor, if there is a chance with his plugin to not do the first login automatic. To redirect after the twitter login to our registration page where the user can add additional data and after that I register the user.